# Why is my shared integer variable only 1 byte?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm *very* new to multiprocessing.
I'm using the multiprocessing library in Python 3.4, and my shared counter variable is maxing out at 127, and then flipping around to -128 leading me to believe that it's only 1 byte in length. Why is it not the size of a normal int?

Here's an example of my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Value

def process(arg1, arg2, counter, checker):
    global attempts
    attempts = counter
    global succeeded
    succeeded = checker

    while not succeeded.value:
        if <expression>:
            succeeded.value = True
            break 
        elif <expression>:
            break
        else:
            <code that does stuff>
            with attempts.get_lock():
                attempts.value += 1
            print(attempts.value)


NUMOFPROCESSES = 5
attempts = Value('i', 0, lock=True)
succeeded = Value('b', False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(NUMOFPROCESSES):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(arg1, arg2, attempts, succeeded))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Output would look something like this:

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
125
126
127
-128
-127
-126
-125
```

Comment: I can't seem to re-produce this. I replaced your missing conditionals with `if random.randint(0,100) == 1:` and it'll happily run to 300 and above without overflowing.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much copied my code from stack overflow and it still did this. Local variables defined in each process are the normal int size, but the ones that are shared are 1 byte. I have no clue what would cause this.

Comment: I switched `attempts` and `succeeded` in the `multiprocessing.Process` call and got the bad result. You may want to check the call in your real code.

Comment: This illustrates the advantage of a runnable example. Both @jDo and I had to edit it to the code to get it to run... and then we find the example works for you too! Your problem is likely that you passed parameters in the wrong order. If `attempts` is a `"b"` format, it is a byte.

Comment: @REVerse - for the benefit of future questions, please read [mcve] from the [ask] section of the help center.

Comment: I suspected that `b` might refer to a byte. Nice detective work, @tdelaney!

Comment: @Robᵩ, Ok. Sorry, this is my first time asking a question on stack.

Comment: @tdelaney, Yep, that was it! The parameters were switched in the process function definition. I spent a long time trying to figure this out and never noticed that. I feel silly for having to ask Stack Overflow for such a simple solution